# how do i convert [Synset('dog.n.01'), Synset('frump.n.01'), Synset('dog.n.03'), Synset('cad

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

how do i convert

```
[Synset('dog.n.01'), Synset('frump.n.01'), Synset('dog.n.03'), Synset('cad.n.01'), Synset('frank.n.02'), Synset('pawl.n.01'), Synset('andiron.n.01'), Synset('chase.v.01')]
```

to

```
'dog.n.01', 'frump.n.01', 'dog.n.03', 'cad.n.01', 'frank.n.02', 'pawl.n.01', 'andriron.n.01', 'chase.v.01'
```

in python

note the original text is the output of wordnet.synsets( 'dog' ) from the NLTK library

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or did you just want us to do your homework for you?

Comment: It helps when you're asking a question to have tried at least one or two things so you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: i dont have code but i tried using mylist = mylist.strip('Synset') @foxygen

Comment: what are the list elements? strings?

Comment: the output is from wordnet. It is a dictionary for python. the list elements are how to lookup the meaning. the next command would be wordnet.sysnet('dog.n.01') if i wanted the first definition of the noun form of dog @PadraicCunningham

Comment: but are the elements in the list actually strings or some other objects?

Comment: the conversion methods i tried showed that it is some other object.@PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this data is coming from NLTK?

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
syns = wn.synsets('dog')
```

If so, try:

```
names = [ s.name() for s in syns ]
```

to get a list of names.

(In the future, please provide more context about where data is coming from.)